# Why are some image captures 10x larger than others?

Tags: c#, screen, capture

When I take a screen capture of Windows 7 current screen the resulting images are between 300kb and up to 3.5MB. What results in such a variation of size of same screen sizes and same quality? And how can this be avoided?

This is my simple code that i use:

```
int screenWidth = Screen.GetBounds(new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0)).Width;
           int screenHeight = Screen.GetBounds(new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0)).Height;

System.Drawing.Bitmap bmpScreenShot = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(screenWidth, screenHeight);               
System.Drawing.Graphics gfx = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage((System.Drawing.Image)bmpScreenShot);

gfx.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, new System.Drawing.Size(screenWidth, screenHeight));

bmpScreenShot.Save(@"C:\\Snap.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

Answer (score 2):

Without more information about the difference between the two screenshots I would assume it was due to the compression strategy of PNG files:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#File_size_and_optimization_software

Maybe some screens you take captures of have much less information in them and can be more efficiently compressed.

Comment: This is spot on. If you're screen capping an image with broad areas of consistent color then it can be extremely compressed compared to say, a photograph.

Comment: They are very similar images of the desktop with one window present in each. It seems that the images get larger in size the more captures are taken within each sessions. I'll try to use a different format which does not support transparency and see the difference.